# Enable and disable multiple buttons in Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++

I'm trying to enable and disable multiple button for years 2016 to 2005, it named as But2016 to But2005, in my C++ program but it didn't work:

when I assigned a variable within a name, like:
    But+"&i"->Enable = false;

it appeared an error that But undeclared. And, when I tried to use indirect variable, it didn't work, like:

```
RadioButton^ But = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RadioButton());

for (i = 2016; i > 2004; i--)
{
  But->Name = "But" + (i);
  textBox1->Text = But->Name->ToString();
  But->Enabled = false;
}
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can't combine Strings together to make new variable names. However, it should be possible to enter the buttons into a container of some sort and iterate over it using a loop.

Below is some pseudocode. Please bear in mind that this is not written in C++, but something like this should be possible:

```
Map buttons = new HashMap();
buttons.add(2005, But2005);
buttons.add(2006, But2006);
... // add all buttons

for (Integer i in buttons) {
    if (i >= 2005 && i <= 2016) {
        buttons.get(i).disable();
    }
}
```